# Is it legal, to use open-source project names on an ad?

Tags: trademark, advertisements

I have a plan to make a team and develop web sites, servers, games to customers. Of course, there will be ads on local TV, newspapers.

So, my question is: **Can I use Open Source project names on my ads?**
Like, NodeJS, SparkJava, and etc? **Or should I avoid to show concrete names?**

<sub>Sorry for my english</sub>

Comment: Actually, it does not matter whether the projects are open source projects or not - that's just the license for the software they produce. What matters is whether the project has a trademark on the name, or whether you are confusing customers by using the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different projects are going to have different policies. You can presumably refer to those technologies you know how to use. You would do well to review particular projects' licenses and trademark policies, then do it again with a lawyer.

Here's the NodeJS policy to get you started.
https://nodejs.org/static/documents/trademark-policy.pdf